# brew services list show started but mariadb cannit connect

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew

I have installed mariadb 10.4 (which is the latest version). And alter one I have install mariadb 10.2 and 10.3 . After that mariadb failed to connect after I reboot.

Here is the list when I run 
`brew services list`
➜  ~ brew services list

```
Name         Status  User   Plist
mariadb      started darren /Users/darren/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
mariadb@10.2 stopped
mariadb@10.3 stopped
postgresql   stopped
redis        stopped
```

I suspect that there are multiple instances of mariadb is running. How do I remove `mariadb@10.2` and `mariadb@10.3` from the list?

I go to this folder `/Users/darren/Library/LaunchAgents/` here is the list in that folder

```
➜  LaunchAgents ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x@  6 darren  staff   192 Oct 16 20:49 .
drwx------@ 66 darren  staff  2112 Oct 15 09:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 darren  staff   810 Oct 14 09:15 com.google.keystone.agent.plist
-rw-r--r--@  1 darren  staff   916 Oct 14 09:15 com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 darren  staff   541 Oct 16 20:49 homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
-rw-r--r--@  1 darren  staff   677 Oct 15 08:40 org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist
```

It looks no LaunchAgents for `mariadb@10.2` and `mariadb@10.3`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do these steps to get back to mariadb 10.3

```
brew uninstall mariadb
brew uninstall mariadb@10.3
brew uninstall mariadb@10.2

install previous version with

brew install mariadb@10.3


brew switch  mariadb@10.3 10.3.16_1



Add /usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.3/bin to /etc/paths
```